# What is equivalent in java libraries to SqlConnectionStringBuilder in C#

Tags: java, esapi

I am trying to solve a security bug in my j2ee project i.e. Connection_String_Injection.
Unfortunately when i google all i get is C# SqlConnectionStringBuilder fix.

Is there any equivalent to SqlConnectionStringBuilder in java libraries.
If so please let me know how to implement it , if not let me know if there is any anternative to it.

Would be thankful to your help.

Regards,
~Shyam

Comment: `String_Injection` sounds like a synonym for SQL injection. What does your code look like? Have you looked at PreparedStatements?

Comment: Code sample would be helpful.  I'm not familiar with any tools within esapi specifically dealing with connection strings, but there's plenty of tools to help with SQL injection if for whatever reason you cannot use prepared statements.

Comment: thanks a lot Rouge and avgstvs.

Comment: thanks a lot Rouge and avgstvs.                                            Here is the snippet     
public static void execute(String args[])throws Exception{
    int numargs = args.length;
    if (numargs < 3) {
        log.error("Usage: ReportAttibuteCondition mssql|oracle infile outdir");
    }
    String dbname = args[0];
    String infile = args[1];
           String outdir = args[2];
          File f = new File(infile);
    if (!f.exists()) {
       impReport.generate(dbname, infile, outdir);
    }
}

Comment: thanks a lot Rouge and avgstvs.                                            Here is the snippet     <br/>
public static void execute(String args[])throws Exception{ <br/>
    int numargs = args.length; <br/>
    if (numargs < 3) { <br/>
        log.error("Usage: ReportAttibuteCondition mssql|oracle  infile outdir"); <br/>
    } <br/>
    String dbname = args[0]; <br/>
    String infile = args[1]; <br/>
           String outdir = args[2]; <br/>
          File f = new File(infile); <br/>
    if (!f.exists()) { <br/>
       impReport.generate(dbname, infile, outdir); <br/>
    } <br/>
} <br/>